# LDAP with Thinktecture IdentityServer

Tags: active-directory, ldap, thinktecture-ident-server

Can Thinktecture IdentityServer (version 2) support authentication against LDAP/Active Directory?  If so, is I'm looking for any guidance on how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: To help clarify what I'm really looking for.  I have a need to have a user authenticate transparently via a form with either LDAP a custom form by checking if they exist in one data store (LDAP).  If not, the fallback datastore (SQL) should be checked.  I thought IdentityServer could help abstract some of this.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the implementation of ValidateUser method [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/blob/master/src/Libraries/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Repositories/ProviderUserRepository.cs#L26). I assume that you have only one LDAP and you do not need client to send some info about the LDAP server.